# how to draw hypervolume with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, technical-drawing

[image]

it is frequently used in multi-objective optimization evolutionary algorithm(MOEA)

or something like this
[image]

Comment: I usually think of "hyper" as 4 dimensions, not 3.

Comment: @Teepeemm you are right ,but it is just a term widely accepted in Multi-objective  optimization field.  Otherwise, what should we call in 2 or 3 dimensional space？

Comment: "area" and "volume"?

Answer (score 12):

Probably not exactly what is required but anyway...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{xxcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{pics/cube/.style args={#1 #2 #3 #4}{code={%
  \path [#4, fill, draw]
    (0,#2,0)   coordinate (-top-a) -- (#1,#2,0)  coordinate (-top-b) --
    (#1,#2,#3) coordinate (-top-c) -- (0,#2,#3)  coordinate (-top-d) -- cycle;
  \path [#4!75!black, fill, draw] 
      (#1,0,0) -- (#1,#2,0) -- (#1,#2,#3) -- (#1,0,#3) -- cycle;
  \path [#4!50!black, fill, draw]
    (0,0,#3) -- (0,#2,#3) -- (#1,#2,#3) -- (#1,0,#3) -- cycle;
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round,>=Triangle,
  x=(330:1cm),y=(90:1cm),z=(210:1cm), axis/.style={ultra thick, ->, draw=black}]
\draw [axis] (0,0,0) -- (8,0,0);
\draw [axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,8,0);
\draw [axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,8);
\begin{colormixin}{85!white}
\pic at (0,0,0) {cube={4 1 4 red}};
\pic at (4,0,0) {cube={2 1 2 yellow}};
\pic at (6,0,0) {cube={1 1 1 pink}};
\pic at (0,1,0) {cube={3 2 3 green}};
\pic at (0,0,4) {cube={2 1 3 orange}};
\pic at (0,1,3) {cube={1 1 3 purple}};
\pic (Blue) at (0,3,0) {cube={1 3 1 blue}};
\foreach \i in {a,...,d}
  \node [circle, fill=blue!20] at (Blue-top-\i) {$\i$};
\end{colormixin}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I label coordinates of a any vetex of a box?

Comment: @minthao_2011 yes，you are free to do so. Actually, it is the union of cubes whose diagonal points are  [0,0,0] and x in Set S

Comment: If I want to label A at (0,0,10), how can I label?

Comment: @ minthao_2011 may be Mark Wibrow is fitter to answer your question

Comment: @minthao_2011 see the updated example which shows how a box can be named and (some of) the vertices labelled.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Thank you very much. Voted for you.